# How to prevent firing ActionEvent when ComboBox value property is changed programmatically?

Tags: javafx, combobox, event-handling

I'm working with ComboBox control and I want to do something easy with it. I want ComboBox to fire an ActionEvent when its value is changed during mouse click on the ComboBox dropdown list (This is automatically done). In the opposite side, I want ComboBox **Not to** fire ActionEvent when its value is changed programmatically (e.g. when using `comboBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst()`).

Here is a simple code to demonstrate the problem:

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox vBox = new VBox();

        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        comboBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("John", "Josh", "Mosh"));

        comboBox.setOnAction(event -> {
            System.out.println("Action");
        });

        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                return null;
            }
        };
        task.setOnSucceeded(e -> comboBox.getSelectionModel().select("John"));
        new Thread(task).start();

        vBox.getChildren().addAll(comboBox);
        vBox.setPrefWidth(200);
        vBox.setPrefHeight(200);
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

As you can see, ComboBox has a `setOnAction` method which should be invoked **only** when ComboBox value is changed by a **mouse click on the dropdown list**. Also, there is a `Task` that does some operations. (Those operations are omitted for code simplicity reasons). After the `Task` is completed successfully, the ComboBox's value changes and `setOnAction` method is invoked too, while the value should be changed without invoking `setOnAction` method. I don't know how to achieve this. Any useful suggestions or tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: not supported .. see the api doc, if you really want it, you need custom logic

Comment: Simply toggle a `boolean` just before changing the value programmatically and check the state of the `boolean` in the `onAction` handler to determine if you should do anything or not; don't forget to toggle the `boolean` again after setting the value programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used Slaw's approach to suppress event firing across multiple controls at once -

1. set up a boolean field

   private boolean programmedAction = false;
2. in the programmatic method updating the control, set the flag first to suppress actions

   private void someMethod(){
   programmedAction = true;
   // manipulate controls
   programmedAction = false;
   }
3. in the control related events, check the boolean before firing

   private void someControlsAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
   if (programmedAction) return;
   // do regular action stuff
   }